# How do I Circle Crop a video?

Tags: android, html, css, video, video-processing

I need a video cropped into a circular form. I've tried it on canva but to no avail. I've done thorough research on how to have this done but to no avail.

Comment: Why not just  clip-path: circle(closest-side);

Comment: @AHaworth is this css?

Comment: Yes, I assumed that’s what you wanted from the given tags.

Comment: @AHaworth Alright. Do I add (closest-sides) to the code?

Comment: @AHaworth how do you mean (closest-sides). Thanks

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66278982/video-with-clip-path-is-not-showing-working-in-safari/66280378?noredirect=1#comment137886120_66280378

Comment: It did. Thanks. Would you mind making it the answer so I can mark it

Comment: Afraid I can’t add an answer as I’m on a touchscreen device. The clip-path I gave you is pure CSS. You can look it up on MDN.